# Database addExpression SUM: Call to a member function execute() on string

Tags: database

I need to get the `sum` of all `points` values of the user with `uid` 1 from the `test_sum_expression` table.  But when I try to `execute` I get this message `Error: Call to a member function execute() on string`.

If I don't execute, I get the count 6 of the word points, as if it were counting the characters from the string points.
[image]

```
$queryPoints = $connection->select('test_sum_expression', 'n')
    ->fields('n', ['uid', 'points'])
    ->condition('n.uid', 1, '=')
    ->groupBy('n.uid')
    ->addExpression('SUM(n.points)', 'points')
    ->execute();


dpm($queryPoints);
```

[image: Mysql table with two columns (uid, points)]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `addExpression()` returns the unique alias assigned to the expression, and *not* the query. You can fix this by adjusting your code as follows:

```php
$query = $connection->select('test_sum_expression', 'n')
    ->fields('n', ['uid', 'points'])
    ->condition('n.uid', 1, '=')
    ->groupBy('n.uid');
$query->addExpression('COUNT(n.points)', 'points');
$queryPoints = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But by mistake in the question I wrote the code with COUNT instead of SUM. My apologies. I've corrected the question. Does this code work with SUM? I'm getting with dpm($queryPoints): $queryPoints Drupal\Core\Database\StatementWrapper#458455 (3)

Comment: `addExpression()` returns a string, whether you pass it SUM or COUNT, so my code is the same either way. Whether that code does what you are hoping is a different question - I am helping with the syntax only.